# ListFragment Textview unnecessary lines

Tags: android, android-layout

ListFragment generates the following view :

[image: screenshot]

I am trying to eliminate the white lines and nothing has helped so far. Any suggestions?

Layout code:

```
<TextView xmlns:android=   "   http:  //schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Genere_list"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/listViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

The code used to create the view:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
    R.layout.test_album_view, Generes.GENERE_TITLES));  
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to write your own ListView XML and use the attribute [`android:divider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:divider) or [`android:dividerHeight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:dividerHeight).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getListView().setDivider(null);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.test_album_view, Generes.GENERE_TITLES));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. Thats perfect! :) Wish i could +1 you, i dont have 15 reputaions :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `ListView.xml` like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:divider="#f19000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

What you want to change are these lines:

```
android:divider="#f19000"
android:dividerHeight="1dip"
```

You can also use

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
```

to make your lines transparent.

Comment: Thank you lambda for the answer, however it does not help as i am using the ArrayAdapter and requires the id to be TextView, i tried using the ListView it throws illegal state exception expecting a TextView

Comment: @amitsalyan Use this by calling `setContentView(R.layout.listview)`, don't pass it to the Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

As said, you have to use this:

```
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

In ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp">
</ListView>
```